# Cambiar de select si el resultado del primero es nulo

Tags: sql

Estoy realizando una query en SQL 2014 y me surgió el siguiente inconveniente:

Tengo que sacar una columna de un query, pero ese dato puede ser null o no, en caso de que ese select retorne un null yo necesito realizar otro query distinto, pero no encuentro como sería la sintaxis para realizar esto

```
SELECT lr.uname AS UserName,
  cast(lr.udt AS DATE)  AS WorkDate,
  StartTime = (
    SELECT min(udt) FROM cp.docleg dl
    WHERE cast(dl.udt AS DATE) = cast(lr.udt AS DATE) and dl.uname =lr.uname
  ),
  EndTime = (
    SELECT max(udt) FROM cp.docleg dl
    WHERE cast(dl.udt AS DATE) = cast(lr.udt AS DATE) and dl.uname =lr.uname
  ),
  NumberOfLegalDocuments = (
    SELECT count(*) from cp.docleg dl
    WHERE cast(dl.udt AS DATE) = cast(lr.udt AS DATE) and dl.uname =lr.uname
  ),
  NumberOfLegalRequest = (
    SELECT count(*) from cp.LegalRequests lrs
    WHERE cast(lrs.udt AS DATE) = cast(lr.udt AS DATE) and lrs.uname =lr.uname
  )
INTO #LegalOfficeProductivityStep1
FROM cp.LegalRequests lr       
GROUP BY lr.uname,lr.udt
ORDER BY WorkDate ASC
```

El campo del que hablo es StarTime y EndTime, como pueden ver, mi idea es realizar un select o el otro según el resultado del primero.

Comment: Hola, para tal caso utiliza el CASE

`CASE WHEN (SELECT min(udt) FROM cp.docleg dl WHERE cast(dl.udt AS DATE) IS NULL THEN 'Valor Correcto' ELSE 'Otra Query' END`

Aunque recuerda, hacer *select* anidados dentro de otros reenlentece mucho una consulta(query).

Comment: ¿Qué motor de base de datos usas?

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurre que primero puedes realizar una comparación, dependiendo del resultado de la consulta que necesitas realizar, algo similar al siguiente ejemplo.

```
IF (SELECT top 1 Campo FROM Tabla WHERE Condicion)is null
BEGIN
 Instrucción 1
END
ELSE
BEGIN
 Instrucción 2
END
```